# How to use an array to order Mysql Result Set

Tags: mysql, arrays

I'm using PHP to paginate the data, but I am trying to figure how I can group the data by price, name, etc. I know I will need to use an array of some sort

```
SELECT PRODUCTS.name,p_id,sku, image, description, model, CATEGORIES.category
id
WHERE PRODUCTS.name LIKE  '%$title%'
ORDER BY p_id ASC $pages->limit";
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for an array of some sort, use the same `ORDER BY` like this:

```
ORDER BY p_id, PRODUCTS.name, CATEGORIES.category, models ASC $pages->limit
```

**UPDATE**

Lets say you have a select that posts the order by, something like:

```
<select name="order">
      <option value="price">price</option>
      <option value="name">name</option>
</select>
```

Then you clean the post and put it in the query like

```
$order = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["order"]);
//and then
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY $order;
```

Comment: I am planning on using a Jumpmenu to sort the data Individually

Comment: sort it individually meaning?

Comment: Like a jump menu that would consist of Sort By: then the options are Price low to high, high to low, Best Selling

Comment: Yeah then you would need to post some variables and the query would change a lot.

Comment: I can give the link of the jump menu item, and define variables for each, and put the variable in the order by statement?

Comment: yes you can, just make sure you clean the variable before you put it inside the sql statement

Comment: Thats my question if my variable is $v= 'PRICE DESC' the sql would be select...from..where ordery by $v, how can I convert the $v into a safer variable for the mysql query

Comment: i updated my answer i hope that gives you a better idea, also be sure to do some research, there is a lot of information for this, like http://ditio.net/2008/06/29/clean-input-variable-php/